# Creating Fulltext Search Optimized

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-text-search

Currently I have the following fulltext index setup:

fulltext on:

Number - Name - Suffix - Direction - City - State - ZIPCode

```
Select id, MATCH(Number, Name, Suffix, Direction, City, State, ZIPCode) 
AGAINST ("Test") as Relevance from test where 1, 
and  MATCH(Number, Name, Suffix, Direction, City, State, ZIPCode)     
AGAINST ("+Test" IN Boolean Mode) HAVING Relevance > 0.2
```

for an address.  It currently is in a MyISAM db type for MySQL, however I'm really not liking how when expensive queries hit, they lock up the entire table, and over a million rows, I'm trying to optimize the best I can.

Would switching to Innodb help with this? Does Innodb support the type of query I have for MyISAM?

Any other suggestions on how to better optimize this query and keep with the full-text search?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB does not support full-text searching.

Another option would be to use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com), which is easy to setup and blazingly fast.

Comment: Will look into this. Are there any other notable differences?

Comment: I worked with fulltext searches for a while when trying to optimize an big application.  The performance was so-so.  We ended up switching to innodb and using additional indexes.  The performance was about the same, although full wild-card search (e.g., '%some%') will be VERY slow.  Finally, I switched to Sphinx and will never look back.  Sphinx integrates well with MySQL, but runs as a separate process.

Comment: Awesome will give it a whirl! Thanks:D